# Insert into table multiple rows with one different value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe my question is kinda simple but I haven't found something like that upon searching.
I want to insert into a table testing multiple rows for example:

('03','ENG','203')
('03','ENG','403')
('03','ENG','155')
('03','ENG','222')
('03','ENG','456')
('03','ENG','111')
...

Instead of writing

```
insert into testing
values('03','ENG','203')
,('03','ENG','403')
,('03','ENG','403')
,('03','ENG','155')
,('03','ENG','222')
,('03','ENG','456')
,('03','ENG','111')

..
```

Is there any faster way to write something like

```
insert  into testing
select ('03','ENG',x)
where x in ('203',...)
```

It would be even better if I did not have to use dynamic sql.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is that much simpler, but you can use `insert . . . select` with a `values()` clause for the third column:

```
insert into testing
    select '03', 'ENG', col3
    from (values ('203'), ('403'), ('155'), . . . 
         ) v(col3);
```

If you have a list of column3's in a table and you have no duplicates, you can use:

```
insert into testing
    select '03', 'ENG', t.col3
    from column3_table t 
    where t.column3 in ('203', '403', '155', . . . );
```

Comment: Used the first one,seems faster to write.